# IOS BLE scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options: on Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

CentralManager doesn't scan BLE device on Background....

I already set `UIBackgroundModes`, `bluetooth-central` in info.plist.

also tried input UUID for service like this..

```
[CentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0xFFA0"]] options:nil];
```

(0xFFA0 is UUID for Service.)

also tried `"C337FA9-4DCF-****-77AB-************";` UUID for device.
whatever I put the UUID in Services. not found any device on Background.

when foreground.. `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil` found all devices.
but not `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:someuuids`

can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you try scan scanForPeripheralsWithServices with some uuid ?And do you get someresult when in this case in foreground?

Comment: No. I didn't get any device, when it scan with some uuid in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

1.if you use

```
scanForPeripheralsWithServices:someuuids
```

There must be some device advertise bluetooth packets with this uuids.This can work well in both foreground and backgournd

2 if you use

```
scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
```

You can get all device you want ,but this does not work when in background.

So,if you want to get result in background,you have to set your Peripherals advertise BLE packets with UUID.